# Faster RCNN - Number of epochs impact inference time

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, torch, faster-rcnn

I have trained two Faster RCNN models with the exact same parameters with the exception of:

1. Model 1: 150 epochs
2. Model 2: 5 epochs

Once the models have been trained, I load them in and then I make one prediction on the same image for each model.

Inference prediction time:

1. Model 1: 70 sec
2. Model 2: 5 sec

To be clear, the time above is AFTER the model has been trained not during training.

**Question**:
How can the inference time increase with the number of epochs?

Libraries:

- tensorvision
- torch

Comment: Are you sure, you are doing everything correctly? It can't be such a difference within 2 models, trained on same dataset, with higher epoch nr..
Btw is it a torch or tensorflow implementation? I see you put tags with tf, then libraries w torch..

Comment: yea I have compared the state_dicts and they are exactly the same. Oh sorry its Torch. I am implementing it in Azure using AutoML.